# Microsoft Tfs build variable gets lost

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am running build with next targets:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeCompile">
    <Message Text="Build no: $(BuildNumber)" />
  </Target>
```

Then in between I run build (using nmake). After that I want to deploy firmware:

```
  <Target Name="AfterCompile">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="CustomDeployMagicFirmware" Properties="Id=1" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CustomDeployMagicFirmware">
    <Message Text="...Deploying bootloader files to build machine - folder: $(BuildNumber)" />
    <Exec Command='xcopy "$(SolutionRoot)\Repository\bootloader\*.axf" \\machine\bootloader\$(BuildNumber) /y /q'/>
    <Exec Command='xcopy "$(SolutionRoot)\Repository\bootloader\*.hex" \\machine\bootloader\$(BuildNumber) /y /q'/ -->
  </Target>
```

The problem is that in target "BeforeCompile" I get properly message output for $(BuildNumber). But later I have Message Test output like:
...Deploying bootloader files to build machine - folder: 
There looks like variable $(BuildNumber) is not set anymore. Also command xcopy copies files to folder bootloader and not to folder bootloader\$(BuildNumber).

What do I do wrong? Which things can influence variable contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in this line

```
<MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="CustomDeployMagicFirmware" Properties="Id=1" />
```

The MSBuild task spawns a new MSBuild.exe process and you are not passing the property $(BuildNumber) to the new process. Change it like below and this would work

```
<MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="CustomDeployMagicFirmware" Properties="Id=1;BuildNumber=$(BuildNumber)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<CallTarget>` instead of `<MSBuild>` to invoke your CustomDeployMagicFirmware target.

Comment: I need to call MSBuild because I run target CustomDeployMagicFirmware multiple times. If using CallTarget TFS will call it only once.